# Understanding a proof of $\eta_1\omega_2-\eta_2\omega_1=2\pi i$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, elliptic-functions

The Weierstrass zeta function $\zeta$ of a lattice $L$ is defined by
$$\zeta (z,L)=\frac{1}{z}+\sum_{\omega\in L\setminus\{0\}}\left(\frac{1}{z-\omega}+\frac{1}{\omega}+\frac{z}{\omega^2}\right)$$
and the quasi-period $\eta$ is defined by
$$\eta (\omega,L)=\zeta (z+\omega,L)-\zeta (z,L)$$
and is independent of $z$. Furthermore,
$$\overline{P}=\{s\omega_1+t\omega_2|0\le s,t\le 1\}$$
is the fundamental parallelogram.

Now Legendre's relation states

> For the basic periods and the associated basic quasi-periods of a lattice $L=\mathbb{Z}\omega_1+\mathbb{Z}\omega_2$ it holds
> $$\eta_1\omega_2-\eta_2\omega_1=2\pi i.$$

The proof is the following:

> We shift the fundamental parallelogram so there are no lattice points on the border of $\overline{P_v}=\overline{P}+v$ with $v\in\mathbb{C}$ and apply the residue theorem:
> $$\oint_{\delta \overline{P_v}}\zeta (z,L)\,\mathrm dz=2\pi i$$
> **because $\zeta$ has (modulo $L$) only one pole with residue $1$.**
> One can combine the values of the integrals along opposite sides of the parallelogram: **The sides parallel to $\omega_1$ contribute $-\eta_2\omega_1$; the sides parallel to $\omega_2$ contribute $\eta_1\omega_2$.** In total, the integral is $\eta_1 \omega_2-\eta_2\omega_1=2\pi i$.

**Questions**

I don't understand the part of the proof which is typeset in bold.

1. What exactly does "has modulo $L$" mean?
2. What exactly does "contribute" mean and why does it contribute $\eta_2\omega_1$?
3. I understand that the residue is $1$ at the origin because of the Laurent expansion at the origin:
   $$\zeta(z,L)=\frac{1}{z}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty G_{2n+2}(L)z^{2n+1}$$
   where $G$ is the Eisenstein series but what about the residues at other poles?

I'm new to complex analysis and the theory of elliptic functions.

Comment: $z_1\equiv z_2\pmod L$ means $z_1-z_2\in L$.

Comment: @TravorLZH I know that, but what does "has modulo $L$" mean?

Comment: It is just saying that $\zeta$ has only one pole on the fundamental parallelogram

Comment: The integral on $\partial P$ is the sum of 4 integrals on each side. The integrals on opposite sides almost cancel each other (the sides are traversed in opposite directions), that's what they mean with "contributes $-\eta_2\omega_1$".

Comment: @reuns What do you mean "almost"?

Comment: $\zeta (z+\omega_1,L)-\zeta (z,L)$ is constant.

Comment: @reuns And where does $-\eta_2\omega_1$ come from?

Comment: @reuns Why is the constant multiplied by $\omega_1$?

Comment: @reuns I know that $\zeta(z+\omega_1,L)-\zeta(z,L)$ is a constant, but how does that help?

Comment: Write $\int_{\partial (v+P)} \zeta(z)dz$ as a sum of 4 integrals.

Comment: @reuns How can I do that?

Comment: It is a contour integral, on the boundary of the parallelogram. It is naturally a sum of 4 integrals, one on each side.

Comment: @reuns Yes, I know, but why is the constant multiplied by $\omega_1$?

Comment: @reuns Can you please provide an answer? Are you able to elaborate? I don't even understand well enough how to set up the integral to be able to use this "almost canceling" property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{eqnarray}2i\pi=2i \pi Res(\zeta(s),z_0) & = & \int_{\partial (v+P)} \zeta(s)ds\\ &= & \int_0^1 \zeta(v+\omega_1 t)d(\omega_1 t)\\&+&
\int_0^1 \zeta(v+\omega_1+\omega_2 t)d(\omega_2 t)\\&+& 
\int_0^1 \zeta(v+\omega_1+\omega_2-\omega_1 t)d(\omega_1 t)\\&+&
\int_0^1 \zeta(v+\omega_2-\omega_2 t)d(\omega_2 t)\end{eqnarray}\\ = \omega_1 \int_0^1 (\zeta(v+\omega_1 t)-\zeta(v+\omega_2+\omega_1 t))dt+\omega_2 \int_0^1(\zeta(v+\omega_1+\omega_2 t)-\zeta(v+\omega_2t))dt\\ = \omega_2 \eta_1-\omega_1 \eta_2
 $$